# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'registeredEventSources[pendindPushEvent.alias].callback') after receiving a push notification

Tags: ios, authentication, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a hybrid application in Worklight 6 and attempting to set up push notifications for my iOS environment. I have been able to successfully subscribe to and receive push notifications on my iOS device. However, when I attempt to open the app by clicking on the push notification I have received, I am seeing this error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'registeredEventSources[pendindPushEvent.alias].callback')

This seems to happen right after I attempt to connect to the Worklight server to do authentication (WL.Client.login) and subsequently prevents either of the login callbacks from being executed. The strange thing is, this event source callback that it seems to be referring to does get called. The function that I pass into WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback is executing and displaying the notification payload.msg correctly.

Note: The authentication seems to work just fine if the app has been opened without a push notification.

I have not been able to find any information on this error elsewhere. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: What is your Worklight version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is IMO a defect. It is fixed in Android but apparently not in iOS. I have opened a defect about it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to define the callback for your push notification:

```
WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
            "myPush", 
            "PushAdapter", 
            "PushEventSource", 
            pushNotificationReceivedCallBack);
```

...

```
function pushNotificationReceivedCallBack(props, payload){
    alert("pushNotificationReceived invoked");
}
```

Can you double check the callback function that you registered with your event source? Maybe there was a typo between the function defined in the "registerEventSourceCallback" call and the actual function implementation?

Comment: I just edited my question. Part of the reason I am baffled by this is because my callback is actually executing. The only real side effect that I am seeing is that I can't seem to get my authentication callbacks to execute.

Comment: Hmm, is there a chance that the javascript is failing in the pushNotificationReceivedCallBack? Can you post the code you have for the callback?

Comment: At this point I am just displaying an alert. (which works)

var receivedPushNotification = function(props,payload) {
    alert(payload.msg);
}